# @font-face with multiple files looks different in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I've css for `Custom Arial` font face for `regular, bold, italic and bold-italic` style.

And for that all different font files are created `arial_mt_stdregular`, `arial_mt_stdbold`, `arial_mt_stditalic` and `arial_mt_stdbold_italic`

```
#span{
    font-family: 'arial_mt_stditalic';
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

In Firefox, this apply italic style twice as Chrome and IE.

So my content looks twice italic and twice bold in FireFox than Chrome and IE.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'arial_mt_stdregular';
    src: url('arialmtstd-webfont.woff2') format('woff2');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'arial_mt_stdbold';
    src: url('arialmtstd-bold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
 }


@font-face {
    font-family: 'arial_mt_stditalic';
    src: url('arialmtstd-italic-webfont.woff2') format('woff2');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'arial_mt_stdbold_italic';
    src: url('arialmtstd-bolditalic-webfont.woff2') format('woff2');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

[sample from FF and Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGsfH.png)

[image]

Why Chrome and IE not applied font-style:italic for "arial_mt_stditalic" font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is browsers trying to simulate italics when you've provided an italic font but told the browser it isn't italic.

When applying the font you have:

> ```
> font-family: 'arial_mt_stditalic';
> font-style: italic;
> ```

But in the single `@font-face` for `rial_mt_stditalic` you have

> ```
> font-style: normal;
> ```

Ie. you have told the browser to use a non-italic typeface as italic.

All the `@font-face` definitions should have the same value for `font-family`, and the other properties then tell the browser what variant, weight, etc. that particular download is.

When you use that font-family the browser matches on the other properties to select the download.

Ie. you should have:

```
#span{
    font-family: 'arial mt';
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 30px;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'arial mt';
    src: url('arialmtstd-webfont.woff2') format('woff2');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'arial mt';
    src: url('arialmtstd-bold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
 }


@font-face {
    font-family: 'arial mt';
    src: url('arialmtstd-italic-webfont.woff2') format('woff2');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}

// etc.
```

Comment: But, I've modified some of the fonts in Italic version so I've to set different font-family 'arial_mt_stditalic ' as per my requirements.

How Chrome not doubles the Bold or Italic effect but Firefox do?

Is there any thing can possible without changing font-family CSS?

Comment: @yogendarji How browsers deal with font not found (in the case in the question: an italic version of "arial_mt_stditalic": the browser doesn't parse the name) is up to the browser.

Comment: @yogendarji That isn't a problem. Same solution works. It tells the browser to use a specific file for the italic version. That the file is modified from the type designers original is handled.